# C# running into troubles with TimeSpan. Converting uptime seconds to days/hours

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm trying to just write a very rudimentary program that checks my cpu and ram usage and tells me the current uptime. If the cpu or ram exceeds a certain threshold It'll verbally announce it and warn me. I'm trying to use the TimeSpan to automatically turn my system uptime from seconds to days, hours, minutes, seconds. When I run the code, it says 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds. However, it announces it correctly in hourswhen I'm not using the TimeSpan.

```
  #region My Performace Counters
        //this pulls the current cpu load in %
        PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        //this pulls the available memory in MBytes
        PerformanceCounter perfAvailableMemoryCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        //this shows the systems uptime (in seconds)
        PerformanceCounter perfUptimeCount = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
        #endregion

        TimeSpan uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(perfUptimeCount.NextValue());
        string systemUptimeMessage = string.Format("The current system uptime is {0} days {1} hours {2} minutes and {3} seconds",
            uptimeSpan.TotalDays,
            uptimeSpan.TotalHours,
            uptimeSpan.TotalMinutes,
            uptimeSpan.TotalSeconds
            );

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", systemUptimeMessage);


        //tell the user what the current system uptime is
        synth.Speak(systemUptimeMessage);
```

Once I run that portion, It just tells me 0,0,0,0 for days, hours, minutes and seconds. However, If I continue to the next portion, I'm able to successfully pull the system uptime in hours.

```
 //infinte While loop
        while(true)
        {
            //get the current performance values
            int currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
            int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfAvailableMemoryCount.NextValue() / 1024;
            int currentUptime = (int)perfUptimeCount.NextValue() / 3600;

            //Every 1 Second prints the cpu load (%) and available mem (GB) to screen  
        Console.WriteLine("Cpu Load        : {0}%", currentCpuPercentage);
        Console.WriteLine("Available Memory: {0} Gigabytes", currentAvailableMemory);
        Console.WriteLine("System Uptime   : {0} hours", currentUptime);        


            //if cpu is over 80 percent, vocally say the current percent
            if( currentCpuPercentage > 80 )
            {
                if (currentCpuPercentage == 100)
                {
                    string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("You're CPU is about to catch fire!");
                    synth.Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage);
                }

                else

                {
                    string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("The current CPU load is {0} percent", (int)currentCpuPercentage);
                    synth.Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage);
                }
            }

            //if available memory is less than 1 vocally say the current available memory
            if( currentAvailableMemory < 1 )
            {
                string memAvailVocalMessage = String.Format("The current available Memory is {0} Gigabytes", (int)currentAvailableMemory);
                synth.Speak(memAvailVocalMessage);
            }





        Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //just an extra space
        Console.WriteLine();

            //end of loop
        }
```

I don't intend to keep the uptime message in the While loop, I'm just leaving it there to check if I'm getting the correct time (which I am). I could easily leave it how it is and just check it for hours by diving the time in seconds by 3600 however, I would just like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the TimeSpan. I'm very very new to all of this So I apologize if I sound dumb asking this.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the counter, the first call will return 0.0.  See documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

You can fix this by adding one additional (initial) call to `NextValue()`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured it out with that help. If I understood it correctly, I needed to call for the nextvalue once before I attempted to put it into the TimeSpan. It's working now at least so I'm assuming that was correct lol. Thanks again.